# The query contains references to items defined on a different data context

Tags: c#, linq

```
   Func<PageDBDataContext,int,int,string, IQueryable<SepiaWEB.Models.Pages.Page>> s_compiledQuery2 = CompiledQuery.Compile<PageDBDataContext, int,int,string, IQueryable<SepiaWEB.Models.Pages.Page>>(
                (ctx, OrganizationId, pagesids,filte) => from pag in pagerepository.GetAllPages()
                            join pgmt in pagerepository.GetAllPageMeta()
                           on pag.int_PageId equals pgmt.int_PageId
                           where (pag.int_OrganizationId == OrganizationId && pag.int_PageId == pagesids
                            && pag.int_PostStatusId == 2) &&
                            (pgmt.vcr_MetaKey.ToLower().Contains(filte) && pgmt.vcr_MetaValue.Contains("true"))
                            select pag );


                using (PageDBDataContext context = new PageDBDataContext())
                {
                    IQueryable<SepiaWEB.Models.Pages.Page> orders = s_compiledQuery2.Invoke(context, 3,1137,"chken");
                }
```

how can i remove this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using pagerepository.GetAllPages() and for sure it's using a different datacontext than ctx. In fact, it doesn't seem like the query uses the datacontext passed as a parameter. As a fix, I would suggest remove the pagerepository references from the query and replace them to uses of ctx, something like this:

```
Func<PageDBDataContext,int,int,string, IQueryable<SepiaWEB.Models.Pages.Page>> s_compiledQuery2 = CompiledQuery.Compile<PageDBDataContext, int,int,string, IQueryable<SepiaWEB.Models.Pages.Page>>(
            (ctx, OrganizationId, pagesids,filte) => from pag in ctx.Pages
                        join pgmt in ctx.PagesMeta
                       on pag.int_PageId equals pgmt.int_PageId
                       where (pag.int_OrganizationId == OrganizationId && pag.int_PageId == pagesids
                        && pag.int_PostStatusId == 2) &&
                        (pgmt.vcr_MetaKey.ToLower().Contains(filte) && pgmt.vcr_MetaValue.Contains("true"))
                        select pag );
```